# Ask Different podcast?

Tags: discussion, podcast

For the past few days I've been thinking about other ways and formats to engage the community in. The town hall went pretty well, as did the live chat during the iPad 2 event.

**Would anyone be interested in listening to or participating in a podcast?**

I'm thinking two to four regular hosts with a guest or two talking about the latest Apple products, news, and rumors, maybe answering some questions from the community, and picking a particularly good or interesting recent question to talk about. Is this a good idea? Would anyone even listen to it? The sadly now-defunct Stack Overflow podcast was very popular, but that was definitely due to the presence of Jeff and Joel.

If you're interested in being on or helping create the show let me know below.

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea. It might be something the moderators can put together to start with and then expand. Once there is enough episodes we could maybe have it featured on the blog.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth, Diago. Not to say it should be limited solely to mods nor active members of this site only.

Answer (score 3):

Could we partner with an existing apple-based podcast of some kind?

Comment: @Jeff Is that a question? ;) I believe that could be possible…

Comment: We could, but I think that we would lose a lot of the benefit because it wouldn't be coming from our community, it would just be an Apple podcast that we're somehow associated with.

Comment: I believe someone could talk Leo Laporte into this. He is very open to proposals and he loves to talk about apple. But we'd need a really good host radio talk alike to come along. :)

Comment: @cawas I doubt that; we can't get Leo Laporte to return Joel's emails even with an introduction by Jason Calacanis

Comment: @Jeff maybe keep insisting? Eventually he must get it.

Comment: Jeff, when was that last the case? Not to start conspiracy theories, but I'm not sure Jason is a good doorway onto Leo's radar. And also, now he has Eileen to manage many administriva duties for him. I mentioned in chat, [Alex Lindsay](http://www.pixelcorps.tv/), and could also think of folks like Gruber and his co-hort Dan Benjamin.

Comment: @VxJason Jeff said "Joel" not Jason. ;) Joel > Jason. ;)

Comment: @Martín: "even with an introduction by Jason Calacanis".

Comment: @VxJason: I stand perfectly corrected :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a nice idea. I'm not a native english speaker but I'll certainly hear it :)

Answer (score 2):

I would be down for contributing however you think you could use it. I have space to host assuming it wouldn't be hosted in SE's network, programming skills to contribute (I designed and maintained [Orange Lounge Radio](http://www.orangeloungeradio.com/)'s Podcast Updater and RSS Feed for years), I have a *couple* (ahem) Blue Microphones, and time to spare... maybe :).

Totally down.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the offer to host the podcast, that'll definitely be useful. How much bandwidth do you have to play with?

Comment: Interestingly enough? Unlimited, and it's not a gimmick. My webhost measures in system resource utilization in preference to bandwidth. I'm sure excessive abusers are kicked off, but I'm not at that point yet :). I have some room to play too, in the form of a second location I can play with, and a virtual server (that I don't call production ready, but can leverage in a pinch).

Answer (score 2):

I'd be willing to participate as a guest, and perhaps more as time permits. I've done lots of radio and podcast appearances over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Neat idea. We're looking at making a podcast where I work at the moment, so been doing lots of reading on the topic. Does anyone else here have experience at making podcasts?

Obviously there are quite a few Apple-centric podcasts out there, but I think an enthusiastic group like us would have a good chance at making a successful run at it.

Great thinking Kyle.

Comment: I have absolutely no experience making a podcast, so any tips or help you can provide would be appreciated. There are a lot of Apple podcasts out there, but they mostly are about talking about the latest news and rumors. Of course we'll do that too, but I think that we could really tap into the Q&A angle through the site here that would hopefully make the format a little different that most other shows.

Comment: @Kyle I have experience in music pre-post production and I'm a mid-pro Logic Pro user if you need a hand in that department.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following the lead of TWiT. It's a great format. They just grab news around and discuss about it. We could grab Ask Different questions and discuss them. Of course, that's just the theme.

I'd definitely love to participate as a guest, but I'm afraid I don't have what it needs for it. And I would most certainly hear it. I'm currently listening to 3 and I'm missing 1 in my week podcast wallet.

Answer (score 0):

sounds fun... i'd be down for helping here and there depending on what is needed