# Ask Different Podcast - Planning Room

Tags: discussion, podcast

There's been [reasonable interest](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/428/ask-different-podcast) in doing an Ask Different podcast, enough that I think we should try to create a pilot episode. There are numerous factors to consider, from the format to the hosts to the time it's recorded. Please feel free to help with the planning below.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I'm thinking so far. Any and all of this can be changed if necessary:

### Hosts/Guests:

- Kyle Cronin (Eastern, Tuesday morning/midday would work best)
- [VxJasonxV](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/428/ask-different-podcast/435#435) (TZ=Mountain)
- [calavera](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/428/ask-different-podcast/439#439) (TZ=Pacific, wouldn't want to be a pure host but i would definitely guest or whatever)
- [Negrino](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/428/ask-different-podcast/440#440) (TZ=Pacific)

### Communication:

- Skype
- [Ecamm Call Recorder](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/callrecorder/), highest quality setting

  - Tests will have to be done to see if the audio quality on the other end of a Skype call is sufficient for the podcast. if not, then each participant will need to record with Ecamm and the tracks will be combined afterward

### Live Broadcast/Chat:

- Justin.TV/UStream
- Ask Different chat

### Format:

- Introduction
- Site news

  - i.e. moderator elections, new Stack Exchange features, etc
- Followup/listener feedback
- Main topic

  - It might be nice for each show to have a theme ("backups", "using iOS with Linux", etc) that we could talk about for a bit. I've (Kyle) found that the podcasts I enjoy and listen to the most are the ones I learn from. And given that this is a Q&A site, we should have an endless source of information to use.
- App of the Week

  - Doesn't have to be every week, but if there's a notable app that's come out or that one of us has discovered, we can do a bit on it
- Question of the Week

  - We highlight a question asked within the last week that's interesting and/or insightful
- Wrap up

### Distribution/Hosting

- Posterous ( http://podcast.askdifferent.net/ )
- Feedburner ( http://feeds.feedburner.com/AskDifferentPodcast/ )
- iTunes

### License

- same CC license as the site

### Name

- It would be nice to be an "official" podcast so that we can use "Ask Different" and "Stack Exchange" in the name and/or description without qualifying it with "community" or "unofficial"

Comment: It would be beneficial to planning times if you folks listed at the top of this answer would specify your timezone.

Comment: @Kyle I would like to be part of this podcast, but at this time I can be a listener as I am not much knowledgeable on Mac OS X...

Comment: @garikapati we might be able to get you on as a guest in the future

Comment: I'd love to join as a guest at least once, @Kyle. So I appreciate if you count me in the first episode. :)

Comment: Wait… I haven't been invited! How's that even possible! ;)  On a serious note, let me know if I can be of service with pre/post production, etc. I could also participate at some point if people are needed. I can only imagine http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVggc7SUhj4 when Manny appears on stage ;)

Comment: Anything specific I can help with? It sounds like most of it is sketched out but it's down to making it happen.

Answer (score 1):

Podcast/RSS Specifications and Resources:

[iTunes Podcast Specifications](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html)
[RSS 2.0 Specifications](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification)
[Feed Validator](http://feedvalidator.org/)